# Query is taking too long even with 1k results

Tags: mysql

I have made several tests to optimize the query below but none of them helped.

What I tried is;

1. Add extra indexes
2. Change query logic by checking other attributes aswell in `IN` clause
3. Tested suggestions of online query optimization tools (eversql etc)

Indexes I am using;

```
radacct (`_accttime`);
radacct (`username`);
radacct (`acctstoptime`,`_accttime`);
```

Complete Query;

```
  (SELECT *
   FROM `radacct`
   WHERE (radacct._accttime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1.2 HOUR)
     AND radacct.acctstoptime IN
       (SELECT MAX(radacct.acctstoptime)
        FROM `radacct`
        GROUP BY radacct.username) )
UNION
  (SELECT *
   FROM `radacct`
   WHERE (radacct._accttime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
          AND radacct.acctstoptime IS NULL) )
```

When I execute `SELECT` statements above by themselves, they only take about few miliseconds.

I have issue with `IN` clause. So this is the query that takes ages

Comment: If you do not want all fields remove `*` and use only required fields. You do not set any limits for your query?

Comment: Hi @KrishnadasPC, thanks for prompt response. I tried with returning only required fields, also with limit. But I found out that the issue is with `IN` clause. I want its results to be checked with proper field instead of checking all results

Comment: hey, why do you do `IN` instead of `=`, since the query returns exactly one scalar value... but apart from that, have you checked the time it takes to execute the IN-subquery?

Comment: did you know about `EXPLAIN SELECT`? If not, you know now. Can you post the EXPLAIN output for both the combined, and the individual queries so we can compare execution plans?

Comment: Hi @Jakumi I cant use `=` because the subquery returns more than 1 row since it will return highest stop time for each `username`. If I execute the `IN` query itself, it takes few miliseconds, but when I execute it with the main query, then it takes about 50 seconds

Comment: okay, my fault, you're right. instead of IN, have you tried to make it a join? like `LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(...) as maxtime, username FROM ... GROUP BY ...) as joined ON (joined.maxtime=... AND radacct.username=joined.username)` - I might have an error in my syntax, but I hope you can fix that. Also I assume username is a varchar column that possibly isn't the most effective way, but it should not matter with 1000 rows

Comment: you might not want the username=username part ... maybe ... ^^

Comment: @Kaii Now I do :), added `EXPLAIN SELECT` results

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks a lot, I will be testing it now, I will let you know if it works as inteded so you can type that as answer also :)

Comment: I'm quite confident on that one ;o)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190356/discussion-between-lunatic-fnatic-and-jakumi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, your problem is the dependent subquery in your `IN`. Apparently the optimizer doesn't get that the subquery technically doesn't change much. (also, the query might be suboptimal). Essentially, the subquery is executed for each row (which is bad).

Now, we have to find out, which part triggers it to be a dependent, because it isn't really. My first try would be to give it a different alias:

```
IN (SELECT MAX(inner.acctstoptime) FROM radacct AS `inner` GROUP BY inner.username)
```

If that isn't enough to make it independent, make it a full-blown join (INNER, such that non-joined rows [= non-max rows] are discarded from the result):

```
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT MAX(inner.accstoptime) as maxstoptime, inner.username 
       FROM `radacct` AS `inner` 
       GROUP BY inner.username
   ) sub ON (sub.maxstoptime=radacct.acctstoptime)
```

Hope that does the trick.

since your result has rows of users with their max `acctstoptime`s, it might - on rare occasions - contain more than one row for a user, when there is a row with a acctstoptime, which isn't the max for THAT user but it matches the max of another user. In the join part, you can just add another condition in the ON-clause. In the IN subquery, you would drop the explicit group by and add `WHERE radacct.username=inner.username`. (which would indeed make it an explicit dependent subquery, but the optimizer *might* be able to handle it)

**update**: due to miscommunication ...

The resulting complete query with the join:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT radacct.*
 FROM radacct
 INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(inner.accstoptime) as maxstoptime, inner.username 
        FROM `radacct` AS `inner` 
        GROUP BY inner.username
    ) sub ON (sub.maxstoptime=radacct.acctstoptime) 
  WHERE (_accttime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1.2 HOUR)
 ) 
 UNION 
  (SELECT *
   FROM `radacct`
   WHERE (_accttime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
          AND acctstoptime IS NULL)
  )
```

you may still add the username comparison in the `ON` clause.

What this query does is, it removes the "IN" selector and force a intermediate result for the join (for each username the max acctstoptime). the join will then join the normal rows to an intermediate result row, if and only if the acctstoptime is the max for some user (or THAT user, if you add the username comparison). If it doesn't have the max acctstoptime and thus no join "partner", it will be discarded from the result (caused by the `INNER`, the `LEFT JOIN` was somewhat insufficient), thus leaving only the rows with a max acctstoptime (in the first part of the union).

Comment: Thanks a lot for great & detailed explanation Jakumi. Unfortunately the execution time is still same. I only changed `IN` part with yours, not helped. then I added `LEFT JOIN` part to new `IN` part, but the execution time remianed still

Comment: mmmh, in that case, can you post the explain for your `LEFT JOIN` variant?

Comment: Updated my question, posted full query and explain variant for LEFT JOIN part. As you may guest I am still learning a lot about mysql and not so expert about it :)

Comment: @LunaticFnatic I updated the answer to reflect what I originally envisioned for the final query to look like.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your time and answers. I really do appreciate it and it works like a charm. The issue was with the server for the query above aswell I think. I ran original query on another server and it took 1~ sec. But yours are even better and I updated my query. Thanks a lot :) About username comparison, you ment `ON (sub.maxstoptime=radacct.acctstoptime AND sub.username = radacct.username)` or I missunderstood again? :)

Comment: no, that's exactly what I meant ;o) glad I could help